# parse a text file and delims : char in batch file

Tags: command-line, batch-file

I am trying to parse a text file into a batch file.
while delimiter with `:` character and extract value of `PageLabelPrefix` and place it into `list.txt`

It seems that only the `%%g` has value, and `%%h` is empty.

Been searching the forum and help. Can't figure what is wrong with it.

My batch file:

```all-bat
@echo off

for /F "delims=:" %%g in ('type "%cd%\data-info.txt"') do (
    if %%g == PageLabelPrefix echo %%g %%h >> list.txt
   )
```

Below is my `data-info.txt`:

```all-bat
PageLabelNewIndex: 1
PageLabelStart: 1
PageLabelPrefix: Sheets: 204 - TYPE A - ATTIC CONCRETE BODY PLAN&#0;
PageLabelNumStyle: NoNumber
InfoBegin
InfoKey: creator_version
InfoValue: 2022
```

Comment: Welcome to Superuser! So your expect result (in list.txt) must be `Sheets: 204 - TYPE A - ATTIC CONCRETE BODY PLAN&#0;`?

Comment: Yes, thanks for reading my post. i had got my result. by using token. i thought it wasn't necessary to add them. as i had seen some examples without token. maybe the code wasn't working in the 1st place.

Answer (score 0):

Two problems in your code :

- The FOR /F command is missing `tokens=` in addition to `delims=`
- The colon (`:`) delimiter is also found in some lines in the text.

Adding the `tokens=` parameter will solve the problem of `%%h`.

However, for the line :

```
PageLabelPrefix: Sheets: 204 - TYPE A - ATTIC CONCRETE BODY PLAN&#0;
```

your code will return:

```
PageLabelPrefix Sheets
```

If this is not the result that you want, you might need to rethink
your batch file.

Reference :
[FOR /F command](https://ss64.com/nt/for_f.html).

Comment: Thanks for the tip, i had successfully got my result.

Answer (score 0):

This is my final iteration.

```
if exist list.txt (del list.txt)
for /F "tokens=1,2,3,4,5 delims=:" %%g in ('type "%cd%\data-info.txt"') do (if %%g == PageLabelPrefix echo %%h %%i >> list.txt)
```

Answer (score 0):

- In **[command-line](/questions/tagged/command-line)**

```all-bat
>.\list.txt (for /f tokens^=1-2^delims^=:^  %g in ('find "PageLabelPrefix" /i ^<".\data-info.txt"')do echo/ %g %h)
```

- In **[cmd](/questions/tagged/cmd)**/**[bath-file](/questions/tagged/bath-file)**

```all-bat
@echo off && cd /d "%~dp0"

>.\list.txt (
     for /f tokens^=1-2^delims^=:^  %%g in ('find "PageLabelPrefix" /i ^<".\data-info.txt"
           ')do echo/ %%g %%h
        )
```

**Obs.1:** There are two spaces in:

```all-bat
...delims^=:^SpaceSpace%%g in (...
```

---

**Obs.2:** You don't need `if exist file (do)` to delete the file, because existing or not, you can directly use `>file.extension (command in block)`:

```all-bat
if exist list.txt (del list.txt)

:: use >.\redirect_to_file.log (from block) ::
>log.txt ( 
       for ... ()do echo/ %%g %%h
     )
```

---

**Obs.3:** You can replace the `type` with a direct command that filters the target strings in file with `find "strings" <file.txt`:

```all-bat
for ...('type "%cd%\data-info.txt"') do (if %%g == PageLabelPrefix echo...)

:: use find "strings" ^<.\"File.eXtension" ::
for ...('find "PageLabelPrefix" /i ^<".\data-info.txt"')do...
```

---

---

**Additional resources:**

- [`CD /?`](https://ss64.com/nt/cd.html)

  - [`CD /d "%~dp0"`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18310141/8177207)
- [`Dir /?`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18310141/8177207)
- [`Find /?`](https://ss64.com/nt/find.html)
- [`For /?`](https://ss64.com/nt/for.html)
- [`For /F /?`](https://ss64.com/nt/for_f.html)

  - [`For /F commands`](https://ss64.com/nt/for_cmd.html)
- [Conditional Execution](https://ss64.com/nt/syntax-conditional.html)

  - [`||`](https://ss64.com/nt/syntax-conditional.html) and [`&&`](https://ss64.com/nt/syntax-conditional.html)
- [Commands Redirection](https://www.robvanderwoude.com/redirection.php)

  - `|`, `<`, `>`, `2>`, etc.
- [How to set multiple `Delims`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57383845/how-to-set-multiple-delims)
- [Why do you need `"tokens"` and `"delims"` in `"for"`](https://www.dostips.com/forum/viewtopic.php?f=3&t=2319)
- [How does the Windows Command Interpreter [`cmd.exe`] Parse Scripts](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4094699/6819406)